# Cannot connect to node js websocket server through nginx with ssl

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, ssl, websocket

I used the websocket protokoll for a period of time and didn't have any problem with that. But now I installed nginx and ssl on my server and cannot connect to that. My setup is quasar (VueJs), Node Js,Nginx, Ubuntu 18.4.

My nginx config:

```
server {
        server_name mySite.mySiteCountry;

        location = /ws/ {

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4510;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
        }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/...; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/...; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

My nodejs server:

```
const app = express();
app.use(cors(corsOptionsDelegate));
app.use(headerSetter);
const sslPort = dev ? 4041 : 4510;
let serverForWs = app.listen(sslPort);

const WebSocket = require("ws");

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
  noServer: true,
  clientTracking: true,
});

wss.on("connection", function connection(ws, request) {
...
```

If I try to connect without ssl to the 4510 port (ws://mySite.mySiteCountry:4510) its working. If I try through the nginx proxy (wss://mySite.mySiteCountry/ws | ws://mySite.mySiteCountry/ws) its not. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I get this error from client. The backend doesn't recieve anything. As I see, the request reaches the nginx, but I don't know what happens after that.
[image]

Comment: Can you please paste the error logs?